# map<int, vector<int> > graph and graph[i].begin() cannot be resolved

Tags: c++

I had this problem where I had a `map<int, vector<int> > graph`
and I tried to access `graph[i].begin()` where `int i = 0;`, and it cannot be resolved.

The error is:

```
error: no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'const map<int, vector<int> >
```

Could anyone explain this? Thanks!

Comment: is there a key with the value zero in `graph`?

Comment: Show the complete code and show the complete error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`operator[]` is not a `const` member, and so cannot be applied to a `const map`.

Why is `operator[]` nonconst? Because it will insert the element into the map if it doesn't exist (which would modify the map).

Answer (score 1):

Note the "const" in the error message. Since operator[] on a map will create the element on demand, operator[] needs to have write access. In your case, it doesn't, so the non-const operator[] is not 
viable.